# binding ajax data objects in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an ajax call which retrieves an array of objects from the server, they are composite objects, for instance:

```
var Person = Vue.extend({
   template: "#template_box_person",
   props: {
       name: {
           default: "unnamed"
       },
       address: {
           type: Object,
           default: function() {
                return {
                     city:"",
                     zip:""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I bind them to the components with v-for in the html:

```
<box_person
   v-for="person in persons"
   :name=person.name
   :address.city = person.address.city
   :address.zip = person.address.zip
></box_person>
```

But it doesn't work, it only binds the name, as usual, but I'm unable to bind the Address object of the Person one. How could I bind a property which is at the same time an object within a v-for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **dot** in props options. You should pass full object at once not value by value.

```xml
<box_person
   v-for="person in persons"
   :name=person.name
   :address = person.address
></box_person>
```